# most efficient way to iterate over a large array looking for a missing element in Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I was trying an online test. the test asked to write a function that given a list of up to 100000 integers whose range is 1 to 100000, would find the first missing integer.

for example, if the list is [1,4,5,2] the output should be 3.

I iterated over the list as follow

```
def find_missing(num)
    for i in range(1, 100001):
    if i not in num:
        return i
```

the feedback I receives is the code is not efficient in handling big lists.
I am quite new and I couldnot find an answer, how can I iterate more efficiently?

Comment: THe more you know the more you can optimize.E.g.  is it a given that all the other numbers occur only once?

Comment: Another common interview question.  Unfortunately, the prob. statement is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any range of numbers, the sum is given by Gauss's formula:

```
# sum of all numbers up to and including nums[-1] minus
# sum of all numbers up to but not including nums[-1]
expected = nums[-1] * (nums[-1] + 1) // 2 - nums[0] * (nums[0] - 1) // 2
```

If a number is missing, the actual sum will be

```
actual = sum(nums)
```

The difference is the missing number:

```
result = expected - actual
```

This compulation is `O(n)`, which is as efficient as you can get. `expected` is an `O(1)` computation, while `actual` has to actually add up the elements.

A somewhat slower but similar complexity approach would be to step along the sequence in lockstep with either a range or `itertools.count`:

```
for a, e in zip(nums, range(nums[0], len(nums) + nums[0])):
    if a != e:
        return e  # or break if not in a function
```

Notice the difference between a single comparison `a != e`, vs a linear containment check like `e in nums`, which has to iterate on average through half of `nums` to get the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The first improvement would be to make yours linear by using a `set` for the repeated membership test:

```
def find_missing(nums)
    s = set(nums)
    for i in range(1, 100001):
        if i not in s:
            return i
```

Given how C-optimized python sorting is, you could also do sth like:

```
def find_missing(nums)
    s = sorted(set(nums))
    return next(i for i, n in enumerate(s, 1) if i != n)
```

But both of these are fairly space inefficient as they create a new collection. You can avoid that with an in-place sort:

```
from itertools import groupby

def find_missing(nums):
    nums.sort()  # in-place
    return next(i for i, (k, _) in enumerate(groupby(nums), 1) if i != k)
```

Comment: the set solution has scored the best in efficiency, thanks. It helps a lot focusing my studies!

Comment: Modifying a list you pass into a function is generally a bad idea, unless the purpose of the function is to change the list.

Comment: @FilippoSantarelli checking for membership in a list is O(n).  Checking for membership in a set is O(1).

Comment: `in-place` sort is saving, `goupby` is cool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter` to count every occurrence of your list. The minimum number with occurrence 0 will be your output. For example:

```
 from collections import Counter

 def find_missing():
    count = Counter(your_list)
    keys = count.keys() #list of every element in increasing order
    main_list = list(range(1:100000)) #the list of values from 1 to 100k
    missing_numbers = list(set(main_list) - set(keys))
    your_output = min(missing_numbers)
    return your_output
```

Comment: While technically O(n), this makes multiple inefficient passes over the list instead of just one pass. Also, your hash tables are going to be large, increasing the chance of collision dramatically.

Comment: Not very efficient as the ^ post indicated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions.